# XPath Query for all element XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm not sure this is even possible since I'm trying to get XPath to return XML, but I have a sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items xmlns="http://www.examples.com/itemsns">
    <item id="1" type="blue">
        <name>Item 1</name>
    </item>
    <item id="2" type="red">
        <name>Item 2</name>
    </item>
    <item id="3" type="red">
        <name>Item 3</name>
    </item>
</items>
```

I'm trying to return the entirety of an element for reference purposes. A client wants to be able to look back at the original XML of an element to troubleshoot XPath queries that may return incorrect or incomplete data.

The goal is to have XPath return the entire element in its original form:

```
<item id="2" type="red">
    <name>Item 2</name>
</item>
```

Is this even possible in a single XPath query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath expressions select nodes in the source document and return references to those nodes. So yes, you can return entire nodes. In fact, you can't return partial nodes.

Now, what you've shown as your output isn't a node, it is the serialization of a node as lexical XML. If that's what you want, then XPath can't deliver it - at least not until XPath 3.1, which offers a `serialize(node)` function. In earlier releases, if the application wants the node serialized, it has to find some other way of achieving that. Most tree models (DOM, JDOM, etc) provide some simple way of serializing nodes, but the details depend on your host language and tree model.